# Evaluate $\int_1^N \frac{-3N+6t-3}{t^3(N-t+1)^4}dt$ when $N=3$ or $N=5$

Tags: polynomials, definite-integrals, summation, closed-form, cauchy-product

Let the **Cauchy product** $$(\zeta(3))^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n,$$
where $$c_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k^3(n-k+1)^3},$$ 
and $\zeta(3)$ is the **Apèry constant.**
Taking $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^3(N-x+1)^3}$ in **Abel's identity** after tedious computations using the division of polynomials, since $f'(x)=\frac{-3N+6x-3}{x^4(N-x+1)^4}$ we've 
$$\sum_{n\leq N}\frac{1}{n^3(N-n+1)^3}=\frac{1}{N^2}-\int_1^N \frac{-3N+6t-3}{t^3(N-t+1)^4}dt+O \left( \frac{1}{N^6} \right). $$

Then I understand that I can't get a closed form from this way since I have an error term that I don't know how compute it, but I've asked to me if at least we can compute previous integral, seems a hard integral, but Wolfram Alpha knows how compute particular values of previous integral. Then since I would like learn more mathematics

> **Question.** Can you explain how get a closed-form, for example for $N=3$ or $N=5$ by specializacion of the previous integral 
>   $$\int_1^N \frac{-3N+6t-3}{t^3(N-t+1)^4}dt?$$

It is neccesary only one case $N=3$ or $5$, I say these because I see that these are posible with this online tool. I will accept one answer with good details. **Very thanks much!**

Comment: Thanks also Jack D'Aurizio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may observe that the given integrand admits a classic partial fraction decomposition leading to

> $$
> \int_1^N \frac{-3N+6t-3}{t^3(N-t+1)^4}dt=\frac{-1-3 N+3 N^2-3 N^4+3 N^5+N^6}{N^3 (1+N)^5}-\frac{12\ln (N)}{(1+N)^5}, \quad N\geq1.
> $$

Comment: Very thanks much, if there ane no mistakes in my evaluation from Wolfram Alpha, the case $N=5$ is $$\frac{161}{6750}-\frac{1}{624}\tanh^{-1}(\frac{2}{3}),$$ and I don't know how is it, from your computations. Of course I accept that your computations are right, but I don't know how deduce it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{1}{n(N-n)} = \frac{1}{N}\left(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{N-n}\right) \tag{1}$$
gives, by squaring:
$$\frac{1}{n^2(N-n)^2} = \frac{1}{N^2}\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{(N-n)^2}+\frac{\frac{2}{N}}{n}+\frac{\frac{2}{N}}{N-n}\right)\tag{2} $$
as well as:
$$ \frac{1}{n^3 (N-n)^3} = \frac{1}{N^3}\left(\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{(N-n)^3}+\frac{3N}{n^2(N-n)^2}\right)\tag{3}$$
hence it follows that:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^3(n+1-k)^3} = \frac{2 H_n^{(3)}}{n^3}+\frac{6 H_n^{(2)}}{n^4}+\frac{12 H_n}{n^5}\tag{4} $$
and the same strategy (partial fraction decomposition) can be applied to the integral resulting from Abel's identity. However, Abel's identity is not really needed to compute the LHS of $(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as Olivier Oloa's answer but giving more details, using partial fraction decomposition, you should get $$\frac{-3N+6t-3}{t^3(N-t+1)^4}=-\frac{3}{(N+1)^3 t^3}-\frac{6}{(N+1)^4 t^2}+\frac{6}{(N+1)^5
   (-N+t-1)}-\frac{3}{(N+1)^3 (-N+t-1)^3}+\frac{3}{(N+1)^2
   (-N+t-1)^4}-\frac{6}{(N+1)^5 t}$$ Each piece is easy to integrate leading to  Olivier Oloa's result.

Comment: Then very thanks much for your confirmation and efforts. I should be know that when I find a quotient of polynomials in the integrand I need partial fractions method. Very thanks much for give more details.

Comment: @user243301. You are very welcome !